# how to show a picture from a location to a ImageView in android?

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` and a picture.
I have the location of the picture like this one:

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.dev.app1/files/Pictures/20120924-092226.jpg
```

How can I show this picture in a imageview?

By just doing `imageView.setImageURI()` and setting the uri to `file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.dev.app1/files/Pictures/20120924-092226.jpg` does not work.

Comment: Are you doing imageView.setImageURI(Uri.Parse(uriString)) or just imageView.setImageURI(uriString)?

Comment: this is the solution :) post this as a answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use imageView.setImageURI(Uri.Parse(uriString)) instead of just imageView.setImageURI(uriString)